# Processing exported executable references

Tags: java, javascript, applet, executable, processing

I want to export from processing an executable.This happens normaly but it makes also 2 folders one source and one lib that stors the .pde and the .jar files that the executable needs. I want to make them exist on the same folder and the executable file to search to its folder not somewhere else. I do not know how to do this at processing.

Also I could just use a java applet and run the jar file only but this does not work if I have  imported libraries in my sketch cause it does not reference them correctly.Can I fix this after the export or before? I do not know how.

Comment: these are two questions?

Comment: basically one problem with 2 solutions that i do not know how to make them happen.I want to use or the applet it i can make it work or the executable

Answer (score 1):

So don't do it in Processing. Export, then copy your files to the same dir. As for the .jar file only: yeah you can, that's the whole point of the .jar file. You don't need any of the other things, unless you're using imports that require libraries, which will be in the lib directory, and you run your jar-packed application by saying which .jar to run it from, and which directory the libraries can be found int. This is how Java works, so if you want it to work differently, the best solution is to ask yourself why. If there are technological restrictions, please mention those in your post (i.e. this might be an XY problem: you want to do X, assume that requires Y, then ask how to do Y instead of asking what the best way to do X is).